# How to change button text color in AlertDialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a AlertDialog with a call and a cancel button.
But i wan't to change the Cancel button text color.

Tried multiple things by editing the style but it didn't work.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.emergency_diag_title)) //AlertDialog title
                    .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.emrgency_diag_desc)) //AlertDialog description
                    .setCancelable(true)

                    //call button
                    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.emergency_diag_call), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.e("RuiterRoute", "Emergency Call triggered by user");
                        }
                    })

                    //cancel button
                    .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.emergency_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.e("RuiterRoute", "Emergency Call canceld by user");
                        }
                    }).show();
```

Comment: First thing that came to my mind is -> Design a layout for your dialog with desired button color. Set the view to your dialog using setView() method and then show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) to have access to Alerts Buttons.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;        
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("title") //AlertDialog title
            .setMessage("msg") //AlertDialog description
            .setCancelable(true)

            //call button
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.e("RuiterRoute", "Emergency Call triggered by user");
                }
            })

            //cancel button
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.e("RuiterRoute", "Emergency Call canceld by user");
                }
            }).show();
    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you Using MaterialDialog : 
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Where you can easily customize and even change your button colour easily

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
        .title(R.string.title)
        .content(R.string.content)
        .positiveText(R.string.agree)
        .positiveColor(R.color.your_colour)
        .negativeColor(R.color.your_colour)
        .negativeText(R.string.disagree)
        .show();
```